# compare objects by multiple fields, how to add in one method?

Tags: java, compare

How can I combine the following compare method in one compare method(comparator1) and (comparator2) ?

´´´

```
private List<Bonus> getBonusListSortedByHasAccountAndDate(List<Bonus> bonusList) {

    final Comparator<Bonus> comparator1 = new Comparator<Bonus>() {
        public int compare(Bonus o1, Bonus o2) {
            return Boolean.compare(o1.isActive(), o2.isActive());
        }
    };

    bonusList.sort(comparator1);
    List bonusList2 = bonusList;

    final Comparator<Bonus> comparator2 = new Comparator<Bonus>() {
        public int compare(Bonus o1, Bonus o2) {
            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
        }
    };
    bonusList2.sort(comparator2);
    return bonusList2;
}


@Test
public void test() {
    List<Bonus> bonus = createBonus();
    List<Bonus> getBonusListSortedByHasAccountAndDate = getBonusDTOListSortedByHasAccount2(bonus);
    assertThat(getBonusListSortedByHasAccountAndDate.get(0).getName(), is("2"));
    assertThat(getBonusListSortedByHasAccountAndDate.get(1).getName(), is("3"));
    assertThat(getBonusListSortedByHasAccountAndDate.get(2).getName(), is("1"));
}
```

updated: for my compare and sorting I want to have "the oldest Bonus created" and "Bonus should be activated"

many thanks in advance.
zoram

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 stream api:

```
bonusList.stream()
        .sorted(comparing(Bonus::getDate).thenComparing(Bonus::isActive))
        .collect(toList());
```

You will need the following imports:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Also, in regards to your test, I would recommend using some tool which does the assertion in a single statement and gives you much better diagnostics. Have a look on [Shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest).

Answer (score 1):

How about:-

```
final Comparator<Bonus> comparator = new Comparator<Bonus>() {
    public int compare(Bonus o1, Bonus o2) {
        if (Boolean.compare(o1.isActive(), o2.isActive()) == 0) {
            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
        } else {
            return Boolean.compare(o1.isActive(), o2.isActive());
        }
    }
};
```

I'm assuming that `isActive()` takes precedence over `getDate()`.

(Thanks to @Jaroslaw Pawlak for pointing out the n00b error).

Comment: Oops!  Thanks, fixed.

Comment: This sort in Java is a stable algorithm, meaning if two objects are considered equal, they won't be reordered. Hence the result will be sorted first by date and then by active (active will have any effect only for cases were dates are equal). So in your comparator, you should first compare dates and if they are equal, then compare active. Of course, it's all subject to what the OP actually wants - just saying that your code does different thing than what OP posted :)

Comment: True, but it's not worth editing until we know what OP actually wants.

Comment: @All, Thanks for helping me. 
for my compare and sorting I want to have "the oldest Bonus created" and "Bonus should be actived".